# Subclassing generic - constructor inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, constructor

I am trying to make a class for variable representation, so I made a parameterized base class  first:

```
public abstract class DataField<Type>
{

    public enum DataTypes
    {
        STRING,
        INT,
        FLOAT,
        TIME,
        DATE
    }

    private DataTypes type=null;
    private String name=null;
    private Type value=null;

    private DataField()
    {
    }

    public DataField(String name)
    {
        setName(name);
    }

    DataField(String name, DataTypes type)
    {
        this(name);
        setType(type);
    }

    DataField(String name, DataTypes type, Type value)
    {
        this(name, type);
        setValue(value);
    }

    public DataField(String name, Type value)
    {
        this(name);
        setValue(value);
    }
    public DataField(String name, String value)
    {
        this(name);
        setStringValue(value);
    }
    public abstract void setStringValue(String strValue);
     ...
}
```

An then made subclases for different types, defining methods:

```
public class DataFieldInt extends DataField<Long>
 ...
public class DataFieldBoolean extends DataField<Boolean>
 ...
```

And so on. But I have an expected problem with String:
Generic superclas has 2 constructors
`DataField(String name, Type value)` to set variable's name and value, and
`DataField(String name, String value)` to set variable's name and value from String, converting it to the required type. But for the  subclass, I have a problem - what constructor to use because they both will be (String, String). So, this code

```
public class DataFieldString extends DataField<String>
{
    public DataFieldString(String name, String value)
    {
        super(name, value);
           ...
    }
```

gives an error about ambiguous reference
How can this be solved? The only method I see is to use something like StringBuilder or StringBuffer instead of String, but it's interesting, is there a "native" solution?

Thank you

Comment: You can use a static factory method instead of constructor

Comment: Sure, factory pattern and so on. But it's interesting how to use a constructors here. I always been wondering about java oop especially after many years of c++ experience, but in this case I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: Ok, just looked at it once more and don't understand - how to use factory pattern in this case? You mean not to use constructors at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can this be solved?

By providing an invocation that doesn't have any ambiguity for the compiler.

> The only method I see is to use something like StringBuilder or
>   StringBuffer instead of String, but it's interesting, is there a
>   "native" solution?

It will work but it also appears clumsy to rely on a *builder of String* to convey a *String* that doesn't need to be build.

The idea in the comments that suggest the use of a `Factory` is not bad but according to your design I think that it will require many changes and make you go away of your actual design : hierarchy of classes relying on a base class.
Because to make things consistent between classes you should define factories in each subclass.
Besides, it will not solve your ambiguity issue if you keep the two constructors in the base classes.  So you should probably allow subclasses to access to the base class fields to perform the constructor logic.

So to stay conform to your actual design, I would solve the ambiguity problem by introducing a new class wrapping the `Type` and the `String` variables.
You could declare this class in the `DataField` class :

```
static class NameAndType<Type> {
    private String name;
    private Type value;
    public NameAndType(String name, Type value ){
       ....
    }
}
```

And so `DataField` class could expose these two constructors :

```
public DataField(NameAndType<Type> nameAndType) {
    this(nameAndType.name);
    setValue(nameAndType.value);
}

public DataField(String name, String value) {
    this(name);
    setStringValue(value);
}
```

In this way you could expose one constructor in `DataFieldString` that relies on one of the base class constructors :

```
public class DataFieldString extends DataField<String> {

    public DataFieldString(String name, String value) {
        super(name, value);
        //  or the other way : super(new NameAndType<>(name, value));
    }    
   ...
}
```

And other subclasses could propose two constructors relying on the base class constructors.
For example :

```
public class DataFieldInt extends DataField<Integer> {

    public DataFieldInt(String name, Integer value) {
        super(new NameAndType<>(name, value));
    }

    public DataFieldInt(String name, String value) {
        super(name, value);
    }

    ...
}
```

And the `NameAndType` complexity/use is not visible for clients of these classes :

```
DataFieldInt dataFieldIntOne = new DataFieldInt("var1", 321);
DataFieldInt dataFieldIntTwo = new DataFieldInt("var1", "321");
DataFieldString dataFieldString = new DataFieldString("var1", "321");
```

Comment: Sure, ambiguous invocation can be solved by providing an unambiguous invocation, I totally agree! ))

Yes, regarding the factory pattern and using another type instead of String - it's exactly what I thought about, I don't like 2nd solution and don't understand how the 1st one could be easily implemented. New wrapper class - too complicated, the idea was to make it simpler. I'd like to make it possible to just use simple `new DataFieldInt("var1", 321)` or `new DataFieldInt("var1", "321")`

At last I can use wrapped String, so only this particular case will be wrapped.. not good though.

Comment: Clients of the class could write `new DataFieldInt("var1", 321)` or `new DataFieldInt("var1", "321")`. Things stay simple for clients. I updated to illustrate.

Comment: Well, got your point at last. It is the same that to remove constructor/replace it with another one. Ok, I can just remove it from the base class then, replacing with another, with different parameters for example.

Comment: I actually removed this constructor, left another one with 3 parameters including type instead. Almost the same but without the inner class. Thank you!